# Perl: Replace many array element with another corresponding array element in a file

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to replace many array element with another corresponding array element in a file, but its taking ages to execute. Is there a simpler approach ? Below is my code:

```
open( my $in,  '<', "Test.txt")  or die "cannot open Test.txt $!";
open( my $out, '>', "TestFinal.txt") or die "cannot create TestFinal $!";
while( <$in>)
{ 
    for(my $i=2 ; $i<=$LastRowGlossary; $i++)
    {
        s/$variable[$i]/$vardescription[$i]/g;
    }
    for(my $j=2 ; $j<=$LastRowTable; $j++)
    {
        s/$COVERAGE_TYPE_CODE[$j]/$TCOVERAGE[$j]/g;
        s/$CVG_TEST_CRIT_CD[$j]/$TCVG_TEST_CRIT_TYP[$j]/g;
    }

    print {$out} $_;

}
close $in; 
close $out;
```

Please advise.

Comment: All the arrays elements are being picked up from an excel sheet. eg: $variable[2] contains "TEMP" $vardescription[2] contains "Temperature" and so on. And the size of each array goes upto 60 or maybe more.

Comment: You should post the content of Test.txt.

Comment: You should probably use some precaution to avoid partial substitutions, such as CAR being replaced in CARCASS.

Comment: Oh Yes! :) ($variable[$i]\b) does the job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes, generating the regex can help:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my @variables =    qw/a b c d e f g h/;
my @descriptions = qw/A B C D E F G H/;

my %replace;
@replace{@variables} = @descriptions;

my $string = 'xaxbxcxdxexfxgxhx';

my $pattern = '(' . join('|', map quotemeta, @variables) . ')';

$string =~ s/$pattern/$replace{$1}/g;

print "$string\n";
```

Comment: Very nice one...learnt quite a few things in just a single post of yours..thank you..

Comment: @choroba I tried your approach. Really a good one! But still the time taken is same.. :(